# how to reverse replicate form data and user profile in CQ 5.5

Tags: aem

I am creating reverse replication in CQ 5.5 for replicating the Form data and User profile from CQ5 publish to the author instance.

(following the link  - [http://www.wemblog.com/2011/10/how-to-set-up-usergroupprofile-reverse.html][1]

Below is the problem scenario :

1. Created **2 Launchers** in author instance for **user** and **group**.
2. In Publish instances's CRXDE, Added properties for the new created User profile under the Profile folder : Path = /home/user/*/profile
   Properties are  : 
   i). cq:distribute=true 
   ii). source=authorname (as key=value )
3. Created 1 more launcher in Publish instance :Add Workflow Launcher Configuration as

> Event Type: Modified
>   Nodetype: sling:Folder Path: /home/users/(.*)/profile Condition:
>   cq:distribute!= Workflow: /etc/workflow/models/reverse_replication Run
>   Mode: publish

1. Created 1 more launcher in Author instance : Create Workflow Model as

> One process step Implementation:
>   com.day.cq.wcm.workflow.process.ActivatePageProcess Add Workflow
>   Launcher Configuration: Event Type: Modified Nodetype: sling:Folder
>   Path: /home/users/(.*)/profile Condition: source!= Workflow: select
>   your model created above Run Mode: author

After following all the steps, the reverse replication is not happening. It is giving the Error 200 page after creating a new user in publish instance.

Please help and correct me if I am missing any step or What is the solution for this Reverse replication  or there is some compatibility issue of CQ version 5.5 and 5.4. Currently I am working on 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set up the reverse replication agent and enable it? There are good instructions here on the official documentation page for CQ5.5:

http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/deploying/configuring_cq/replication.html

**Updated link:**
https://web.archive.org/web/20150907032514/http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/deploying/replication.html

Comment: The link is live, or for the latest version (5.6.1) see http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/replication.html - the instructions are the same.